# java is not working on my recently updated windows 10 computer

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10

I reinstalled the jdk after the installation of the new operating system, and set the environment variable of the system accordingly. I also restarted the computer after the reinstallation and the setup of new environment variable. Still, i am not able to run any java programs on my computer.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B2D6F26E24ACBDB2!2168&authkey=!AJaB6lD3MDO37hA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B2D6F26E24ACBDB2!2167&authkey=!ADKlC8-dOFuH77Y&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: what does $java -version say

Comment: And what happens when you try? "Not working" really doesn't give us much information.

Comment: This doesn't seem like Stack Overflow material -- maybe Server Fault? Is there a better stack exchange?

Comment: I have just shared the links of two screen shots.. kindly check them out.. @JonSkeet

Comment: There's no need for screenshots here. Just a *text* representation of what happens on the console.

Comment: (The problem in the second screenshot is simply that you haven't put quotes around "Program Files". That wouldn't have worked before, either.)

Comment: It's also not clear why you've got a JAVA_NEW environment variable or what you expect that to achieve.

Comment: I changed the variable from JAVA_NEW to JAVA_HOME. and tried using quotes around "Program Files". Still not working..!

Comment: Quote entire path to exe "c:\program files\java\whatever\bin\java.exe" -version. Or is it installed on program files(x86) folder?

Comment: no, its not installed on program files(x86) folder... it's in program files folder.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman "*Server Fault is a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment.*" => probably not - maybe superuser...

Answer (score 2):

1. if you install jdk and java SE correctly 
   2.then download netbeans from netbeans.org/downloads/. Make sure that you are downloading netbeans 8.0.1. it will automatically fix errors and install necessary file.
2. after installation go on Cmd and type Javac 
   follow will be the screen of cmd after running this specific command
3. enjoy java :) 
   [image]

Comment: instead of `javac`, better to try `javac -version` in case you have several versions installed - that way you make sure that the default version is the one you just installed.